# QLNet Implied volatility

Tags: c#, quantlib

I am using QLNet for american option pricing, but it doesn't work.
i have posted my question on [Quantlib forum](http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Implied-Volatility-td7280.html#a13812)

my code:

```
 todaysDate & settlementdate = 2012-12-18, maturity = 2013-01-18,

 Calendar calendar = new TARGET();

 Settings.setEvaluationDate(TodaysDate);
 DayCounter dayCounter = new Actual365Fixed();

 Handle<Quote> underlyingH = new Handle<Quote>(new SimpleQuote(100));
 var flatTermStructure = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(new FlatForward(SettlementDate, 0.08, dayCounter));
 var flatDividendTS = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(new FlatForward(SettlementDate, 0, dayCounter));
 var flatVolTS = new Handle<BlackVolTermStructure>(new BlackConstantVol(SettlementDate, calendar, 0.2, dayCounter));
 StrikedTypePayoff payoff = new PlainVanillaPayoff(Call, 101);
 var bsmProcess = new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, flatDividendTS, flatTermStructure, flatVolTS);

 Exercise exerciseEngine = exerciseEngine = new AmericanExercise(SettlementDate, Maturity); 
 VanillaOption optionEngine = new VanillaOption(payoff, exerciseEngine); 

 optionEngine.setPricingEngine(new BinomialVanillaEngine<CoxRossRubinstein>(bsmProcess, 801)); 

 //error:
 optionEngine.impliedVolatility(optionEngine.NPV(), bsmProcess, 1.0e-4, 100, 1.0e-7, 4.0);
```

underlying = 100, k=101, i=0.08, vol=0.2,div=0,
todaysDate & settlementdate = 2012-12-18, maturity = 2013-01-18,

In **VanillaOption.cs**, the code of case Exercise.Type.American is uncomment;

The error message is: **An item with the same key has already been added**.
at line 111 (results.additionalResults.Add priceCurve, prices_) in **FDStepConditionEngine.cs**

Thanks for kindly help.

Comment: Hard to say if you don't tell us the values you're passing, or even the error message you're getting.

Comment: Still missing some info, such as how you initialize bsmProcess, the option type, your initial setup...  May you post a runnable example?

Comment: Sure, the codes are posted

Comment: I've run the same statements with the Python module (which calls into the C++ library) and I get the expected result (0.19997, which is within the tolerance you specified).  It looks like a problem specific to the C# port in QLNet; sorry I can't be of help on that.  Do they have a mailing list or a forum you can try?

Comment: Thanks for @LuigiBallabio 's advice. Currently I decided to use C++ library for development and everything goes right.